# asp FileUpload Server control fakepath

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, servercontrols

In a asp.net FileUpload server control, when I upload a file, the whole path of the file appears. But I do not want to show the full path.

I want to show something like c:\FakePath\FileName.

Is it possible? and if yes how.

Thanks

Comment: Where does it show the whole path? database? folder in your solution?
Give me a little more and i can easy tell you how to save it so it only how example the name

Comment: I know your trying to solve it, but then try to show me your C# code or some more information about it.

Comment: The problem i am trying to solve is, when my file name is huge(220 characters) and its on desktop, fileupload control takes the entire path of the file plus file name, decides that its more than 255 characters(max file name length in windows) and does not add this file. The path is shown in the text box where I upload the file. if it was fakepath, then the file name size would be smaller.

Comment: As is said, do you have any code you can add? it helps alot to see what your have been writing

Comment: okie..will create a sample and share it here..thanks once again